# Android client socket killed by VM

Tags: android, sockets

i'm creating a app for connect to a java implemented server that connect to a mysql database, from server side everything ok, on the android everytime i connect to the server i can send the message but when reading response socket was closed, i think the problem come from VM that kill the thread, i google'it and attempt to run socket class as an Activity and after as a Thread i even try to give priority to the Thread but i get always the same error:

```
12-28 18:28:24.769: W/System.err(1342): java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
12-28 18:28:24.769: W/System.err(1342):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.read(Native Method)
12-28 18:28:24.769: W/System.err(1342):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.read(BlockGuard.java:273)
12-28 18:28:24.769: W/System.err(1342):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:458)
12-28 18:28:24.769: W/System.err(1342):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:59)
12-28 18:28:24.769: W/System.err(1342):     at java.io.DataInputStream.readLine(DataInputStream.java:310)
12-28 18:28:24.769: W/System.err(1342):     at com.example.lightreading.ConnectionDB$clientCon.run(ConnectionDB.java:83)
12-28 18:28:24.769: W/System.err(1342):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Here is my code using Thread:

```
public class ConnectionDB{

public static String ip;
public static int port;
private static ConnectionDB instance = null;

private StringBuilder sb;
private String response = "";
private String data;


public static ConnectionDB getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new ConnectionDB();
      }
      return instance;
}

public String connect(String s_send) throws InterruptedException{
    data = s_send;
    Thread cThread = new Thread(new clientCon());
    cThread.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
    cThread.start();

    return response.toString();
}


class clientCon implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket = null;
    private DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    private DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
              socket = new Socket(ip,port);
              dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
              dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
              Log.d("sending msg: ",data);
              dataOutputStream.writeBytes(data);
              dataOutputStream.flush();
              dataOutputStream.close();
              Log.d("msg sent: ", data);

              while ((data = dataInputStream.readLine()) != null) {
                    Log.d("data from server: ", data);
                    sb.append(data);
              }
              Log.d("msg received: ", sb.toString());
             } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
             } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
             }
        if (sb != null){
            response = sb.toString();
            Log.d("Response from server: ", response);
        }else{
            Log.d("Response from server is null", "");
        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you have to socket.shutdownOutput(); in order to the socket gets ready to transmit data